# convert linked list to number in python

Tags: python, list, numbers

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self,value=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None
```

the above class is the node defintion

```
def number_to_list(number):
    head,tail = None,None
    p = True
    for x in str(number):
        if x=='-':
           p = False
           continue
        else:
          if p:
             node = Node(int(x))
          else:
             node = Node(int("-"+x))
        if head:
           tail.next = node
        else:
            head = node
        tail = node
    return head
    pass
```

this is the code for conversion of a number to linked list
for example,

```
 assert [1,2,0] == number_to_list(120)
 assert [0] == number_to_list(0)
 assert [-1, -2, 0] == number_to_list(-120)
```

but, how should i convert from linked list to number

```
 def list_to_number(head)
 pass
```

for example,

```
 assert 120 == list_to_number([1,2,0])
 assert -120 == list_to_number([-1,-2,0])
```

i am trying from last 3 days but i didn't encounter any solution please help me from out of this

Comment: What if the input is `[-1, 2, -3]`?

Comment: then the answer should be -123 @thefourtheye

Comment: how do you determine whether a number is negative, specifically, what would `list_to_number([1,2,-1])` return?

Comment: the code is not checks that type of input,it only checks if the full list is negative or positive if it is negative it gives negative number otherwise positive number @Adeeb

Comment: what do you mean by : the full list is negative? do you mean that you can find one or more negative number in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution just for the sake of variety:

```
def list_to_number(a_list):
  a = ''.join(str(abs(i)) for i in a_list) 
  if any(n < 0 for n in a_list):
    a = '-%s' % a
  return int(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a list will return a negative number if it contains atleast one number,

```
def list_to_number(somelist):
    neg=False
    num = ''
    for number in somelist:
        val = str(number)
        if (val.find('-')!= -1):
            neg = True
        num=num+val.replace('-','')
    if (neg==False):
        return int(num)
    else:
        return -1*int(num)
```

Hope this is easy enough to follow.

**EDIT**

I understand from your comment that you have a linkedlist setup as opposed to a list. That shouldn't be a problem, the logic should remain the same. The only thing that changes would b how you iterate, I cannot give the code as that would be doing your homework for you.

Comment: but it is giving the error TypeError: 'Node' object is not iterable please help me to solve this..

Comment: your example, `assert -120 == list_to_number([-1,-2,0])` says you require the method to take in a list. Why are you giving it a node object?

Comment: here in these first i created the list using node object in the same assignment only i have to convert the linked list to nummber so the error came @Adeeb

Comment: I am not sure if I follow but are you saying your list does not contain numbers but nodes? If so, that shouldn't be an issue. I cannot show you how to do it as you wouldn't learn anything, however, i'll leave it up to you to change the code accordingly to work for that case (as a way of testing whether you understood it)

Comment: i tried,but i didn't get the answer can you give me a hint to do it @Adeeb